# How can I group a pandas dataframe at rows which contain NAs and assign an index to the groups?

Tags: python, pandas

I think if the following example should explain my problem.
The result should look like this:

````
|   datetime   value    block_nr   |
+----------------------------------+
|   …15:00     22.5            1   |
|   …15:05     22.0            1   |
|   …15:10     22.5            1   |
|   …15:15     NA              0   |
|   …15:20     NA              0   |
|   …15:25     23.0            2   |
|   …15:30     21.0            2   |
|   …15:35     21.5            2   |
|   …15:40     NA              0   |
|   …15:45     NA              0   |
|   …15:50     NA              0   |
|   …15:55     21.4            3   |
+----------------------------------+```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with test non missing values by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and for repeat values is used compared by shifted values chained with `s` and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
s = df['value'].notna()
df['new'] = np.where(s, (s.ne(s.shift()) & s).cumsum(), 0)
print (df)
   datetime  value  block_nr  new
0     15:00   22.5         1    1
1     15:05   22.0         1    1
2     15:10   22.5         1    1
3     15:15    NaN         0    0
4     15:20    NaN         0    0
5     15:25   23.0         2    2
6     15:30   21.0         2    2
7     15:35   21.5         2    2
8     15:40    NaN         0    0
9     15:45    NaN         0    0
10    15:50    NaN         0    0
11    15:55   21.4         3    3
```